# logback FileAppender -> AsyncAppender flush signal

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I am using a homegrown variant of FileAppender which is attached to an AsyncAppender. I am creating a FileAppender per writing thread. I have noticed that when my thread stops (finishes out of the while loop in run() ), there is data still left in the buffer of the FileAppender.

How does the writing thread in sl4fj/logback signal to the Appender that it is now done and the appender should flush?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have two possible sources of withheld events:

- AsyncAppender
- FileAppender

According to the logbook docs, you can force the FileAppender to flush immediately:

> `<immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>`

According to the docs the AsyncAppender will flush …

> Upon application shutdown or redeploy, AsyncAppender must be stopped in order to stop and reclaim the worker thread and to flush the logging events from the queue. This can be achieved by stopping the LoggerContext which will close all appenders, including any AsyncAppender instances. AsyncAppender will wait for the worker thread to flush up to the timeout specified in maxFlushTime. If you find that queued events are being discarded during close of the LoggerContext, you may need to increase the time out. Specifying a value of 0 for maxFlushTime will force the AsyncAppender to wait for all queued events to be flushed before returning from the stop method.

As long as (a) you are stopping the LoggerContext and (b) your pending events can be flushed within the timeout specified in maxFlushTime then you won’t lose any events.

But, of course, you are seeing data left behind so …

- If the data is left behind in the AsyncAppender then just ensure that you are shutting down the LoggingContext (you can use a [shutdown hook](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#stopContext) to ensure that this happens)
- If the data is left behind in your homegrown variant of FileAppender then consider adding an equivalent of logback’s `immediateFlush` feature to your appender.

Comment: Thanks, adding "immediateFlush" wasn't an option as it would kill the performance of the app. I ended up creating a Stop marker which gets added to the last message. The appenders check for this stop marker and if found flush the buffer to the disk.